# Sublime Text returning nul control character

Tags: sass, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, nul

This seems to happen sporadically but every so often, a nul control character will appear in my Sublime Text editor. The file types are not limited - so far it has appeared in .scss, .html, .php and .js files. Its particularly annoying when editing .scss files as it returns string errors in the command line when running a sass --watch and so breaks the SASS to CSS compiling. It is not always obvious, the watch error will be returned and i must close my source file and reopen to see the control character.

[image]

Any help diagnosing this annoying issue is much appreciated.

Comment: thanks @MattDMo, i did not have the reputation rating to add images :)

Comment: You've tagged both Sublime Text 2 *and* 3. Does this happen on both versions?

Comment: @Novocaine Yes it has occurred on both versions.

Comment: Added this to Sublimes GitHub issues page: https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/476

Answer (score 4):

With regex enabled, find and replace `\x00` with nothing. All `NUL` characters are gone..

Comment: Just what I was looking for safe.